# rtl8822be wifi driver ubuntu 20.04 hp 15-da1009ne

Tags: drivers, wireless, hp

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 via upgrading from 19.10. Everything was OK but Bluetooth. I was trying to solve the Bluetooth issue(No Bluetooth driver found even on 19.10). But happened to lose the wifi driver :(

Here is the log

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

---

```
*-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
```

I was trying to install with the instruction on https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88 but no success. Any help would be appreciated. (I wonder how can I reinstall the original ubuntu drivers? That was working for wifi)

Comment: From askubuntu.com/help/on-topic supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. 20.04 isn't released as an LTS yet and is expected to be released on 23rd this month UTC,your question will become on-topic then.

Comment: @kortewegdevries  would you please say the time and date? furthermore, the problem was also with 19.10, In my local time it is 2020 April 23rd

Comment: Currently there is no Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, there is only *focal fossa* which will be renamed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on release. UTC time is used, and my local time it'll be Friday 24-April-2020 when I expect 20.04 to be released, but there is no specific time, it's when it's ready (if it's not ready, it'll get pushed a week).  It's still somewhat early morning London time (where Canonical headquarters are) so there is a lot of Thursday left there.

Comment: @guiverc In reality, the problem is not with the distribution. the problem is that the driver lost. How can I get it back?

Comment: Drivers are kernel modules, and *focal fossa* uses a different kernel to Ubuntu 19.10, so it needs to be recompiled for the newer kernel used by *focal fossa*.  That however is off-topic here.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *focal fossa* [20.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is 23rd April 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: @guiverc so you say that with the official release of Ubuntu 20.04 drivers, the problem would solve automatically?

Comment: That is not what I said, and this is not the appropriate place (some RCs just dropped... gotta test)

Comment: Sorry to answer my question, but to those who have encountered this problem (or similar), the solution is on https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?45021-rtl8822be-wifi-not-working-after-updated-to-kernel-5-2-0 (red answer)

Answer (score 3):

A guy called mid-kid has a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mid-kid/r8822be) with the RTL8822BE driver that works flawlessly in Ubuntu 20.04 for me.

Here's how to setup the driver:

```sh
sudo apt install build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/mid-kid/r8822be.git
cd r8822be
./make

# remove the misbehaving rtw88 module
sudo rmmod rtwpci rtw88

# install the r8822be module
sudo ./make install
sudo modprobe r8822be
```

The WiFi card should be active now.

Comment: I got an error in the last command: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'r8822be': Operation not permitted

Comment: @AshishMehta, did you run the command with `sudo`?

Comment: Worked flawless for me. Question: Does it break in future kernel updates?

Comment: @tommyalvarez, it shouldn't break in 20.04 as the kernel versions in 20.04 should be API-compatible.

Comment: @mrts sadly it did break after some update from ubuntu :(. Had to re install it. Do you know how to go on installing this driver with dkms or something so it persists okay through kernel updates?

Comment: @tommyalvarez, sorry, I don't know that. You can raise the issue in Ubuntu official support channels so that it will have visibility upstream, maybe they have some advice. Please report back if you get any information.

Comment: @mrts, Yes I did it.