# How To Resolve Wifi Driver Problem on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, broadcom, realtek-wireless

I am encountering a problem while installing the wireless driver in my ubuntu 20.04 version also facing the same issue with (Ubuntu 18.04).

I have gone through [rtl8822be wifi driver ubuntu 20.04 hp 15-da1009ne](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229669/rtl8822be-wifi-driver-ubuntu-20-04-hp-15-da1009ne).

These are the steps which I am following:

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
git checkout extended
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de
sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

But while executing the the `sudo make install`, I am getting this error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-28-generic/build M=/home/username/rtlwifi_new modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-28-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/username/rtlwifi_new/rc.o
/home/username/rtlwifi_new/rc.c:336:11: error: initialization of ‘void * (*)(struct ieee80211_hw *, struct dentry *)’ from incompatible pointer type ‘void * (*)(struct ieee80211_hw *)’ [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  336 |  .alloc = rtl_rate_alloc,
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/username/rtlwifi_new/rc.c:336:11: note: (near initialization for ‘rtl_rate_ops.alloc’)
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /home/username/rtlwifi_new/rc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1719: /home/username/rtlwifi_new] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-28-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:85: all] Error 2
```

The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Broadcom BCM43142 802.11bgn 1x1 WiFi Adapter + BT 4.0 combo adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:2230]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Added the output for the command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` @Pilot6 .

Comment: You have a Broadcom Adapter. Why would you try to install Realtek drivers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: No  @Pilot6 it didn't solved the problem for me. I went through all the steps in the link [https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers] and did uninstall the Realtek drivers. But it didn't work out.
But the steps which i have mentioned in the question did work for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something is wrong with that source in newer kernels, so use this instead

```
sudo apt install dkms
cd
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
```

Check `mokutil --sb-state` as Secure Boot needs to be disabled
Reboot

Comment: ```sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414[/code]```
what is this command exactly as i am not very familier with this and getting error ```does not exist```.

Comment: Run just one line at a time in terminal

Comment: It worked for me @Jeremy31 . But now the problem is that it only connects to the wifi when my machine is turned on or restarted (I know, very rare), if I intentionally turn off the wireless network and try to connect to my network, it no longer connects, and I have to restart or turn off (which is very annoying).
[error connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5aEC.png)

Comment: @RichiJoel try https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1833055#p1833055

Comment: Thank you A LOT! Spent last 2 hours trying to resolve my issue! Your answer did it!

Comment: I can't fugure out how the realtek driver solved an issue with a broadcom device ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 I don't know but I posted the answer almost 24 hours before it was revealed to be a Broadcom device

Comment: you saved my life. thanks mate!

Answer (score 2):

The following commands worked perfectly to get Broadcom BCM43142 working on ubuntu 20.04. You need to do each one.

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-source
sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-common
```

Comment: This helped me with my Broadcom BCM4360