# WiFi Not Working On Ubuntu 18.04 after April-May 2020 kernel update

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers, kernel, realtek-wireless

I have an HP laptop. WiFi is not working in the recent update for Ubuntu 18.04.04. The Realtek rtl8732be adapter is not connecting and giving an error when I 'sudo modprobe' them.

Here is the error:

`FATAL: Module rtl8732be not found in directory /lib/modules/5.3.0-51-generic`

Or, when I try to reinstall them:

```
rmmod: ERROR: Module rtl8723de is not currently loaded
```

I followed this link as it started the WiFi for me -
[How To Resolve Wifi Driver Problem on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235303/how-to-resolve-wifi-driver-problem-on-ubuntu-20-04)

But when my laptop goes to sleep then WiFi doesn't begin to work and gives constant **Activation of network error**. This problem didn't happen for ethernet as I didn't have any problem for it. Have looked up multiple askubuntu pages and couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try also the next solution taken from [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/04/nstall-rtl8723de-wifi-driver-ubuntu-19-04/):

```
sudo apt install git build-essential dkms
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
sudo dkms add ./rtw88
sudo dkms install rtw88/0.6
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

> And Wifi works after reboot without doing any configuration, at least
> in my case in Ubuntu 19.04.
>
> If not, try command to write it into configuration file (replace 3 to 1, 2 or 4 if signal is weak).
>
> ```
> echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=3" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf
> ```

Comment: Please check: `modinfo rtl8723de` I believe that the only available selections for ant_sel are 0, 1 or 2.

Comment: Wifi started for me through the link I mentioned but stopped working if my laptop got in suspend/sleep mode. To overcome I needed to restart my laptop each and every time. I tried this solution and got error that **rtl8723de was still in use**. I restarted and ran the command again. Wifi worked even after waking from sleep. Default ant_sel=0 was giving the best signal. Thanks for the help @Gryu.