# Wifi not working on Linux ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, intel, iwlwifi

I've just installed linux ubuntu 20.04 in dual boot with Windows 10 and i can't use the Wifi. I think the problem is with the drivers because with Win it all works perfectly.

I've tried this command :

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
```

and this is the result:

```
  *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: eno2
   version: 15
   serial: 0c:9d:92:34:14:48
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-45-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4304000-a4304fff memory:a4300000-a4303fff


*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   version: 78
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:a4200000-a4201fff
```

I think the problem is that the network controller is listed as "UNCLAIMED".

I don't know what information will you need to help me, just ask and I can give all the info needed.

Thank u guys :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, which in my case boiled down to Netgear wifi adapters not supported by Ubuntu. First, I would verify your adapter is supported here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported

Then I would suggest reviewing other solutions here:

[How To Resolve Wifi Driver Problem on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235303/how-to-resolve-wifi-driver-problem-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: My adapter is Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275, i can't find it in the link u give me but I'm sure it works on Ubuntu 20.04 because I've already installed it before