# Problem with internet connection on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, internet, connection, modem

I can't connect to the internet on Ubuntu 20.04.
I checked many things:

1. The wireless adapter is enabled.
2. Localhost ping is OK.
3. Ping to `8.8.8.8` is ok.
4. I can connect to the Internet via cable.
5. I can connect to the Internet through a mobile hotspot.
6. I reinstalled my wireless network drivers
7. I updated my software driver

Although I can connect to the Internet through the modem with other devices, my laptop cannot connect to the Internet in the same way.

The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

The output of `uname -a; dkms status`:

```
Linux siamak-HP-Notebook 5.19.0-32-generic #33~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jan 30 17:03:34 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Is it a new install? Did you have this problem from the beginning, or did it happen after you did something? Also the question is unclear. If you can ping 8.8.8.8, it means that you have an internet connection.

Comment: No, the installation is not new and I had no problem until the day before this problem started two days ago. Yes, it is confusing for me too. But in my opinion, the connection is very weak, and while there is apparently internet, no page opens.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: OK, please add output of `uname -a; dkms status` output.

Comment: Try to boot with a previous 5.15 kernel using grub menu and check.

Comment: Although I changed the kernel to 5.15, nothing changed and I have the previous problem.

Comment: It can be a hardware problem too. Like a bad connection of an antenna.

Comment: I think so, Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: This answer solved my problem. https://askubuntu.com/a/1309059/1675384

Comment: That answer could not solve your problem it is unrelated to your hardware. You don't have a Broadcom device.

Comment: This problem confused me. If it was related to the hardware of my system, it should not connect to the Internet with other routers. And if the problem was with the modem, I should not connect to the Internet with devices through this modem. I checked many things but interestingly this answer solved my problem.

Comment: It is a coincidence. That answer installs drivers for a device that you don't have.

Comment: I made some changes to the network card settings almost at the same time, and on the other hand, the signal may be weak. For some reason, the signal strength improved because I connected to different networks at the same time. I connected to the internet through some, but not through others. So, it is most likely that the signal strength of the routers has improved because I do not have access to them to check and apply the settings, and the problem is not with the system hardware. And all these things happened at the same time :-). Thank you.