# RealTek drivers not working with Ubuntu 20.04 kernel: 5.4

Tags: drivers, kernel, lenovo, 20.04, realtek

I am getting a hard time to enable wifi on legion 530 with Ubuntu 20.04.

Things I tried so far,

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
rebooted
```

> I could see wifi enabled but it was not able to detect any available networks.

Then I tried:

```
echo "options r8822be aspm=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/r8822be.conf
sudo rmmod r8822be
rmmod: ERROR: Module r8822be is not currently loaded
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Details:
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Wifi: Realtek r8822be
Laptop: Lenovo Legion

```
nitish@Lenovo-Legion-Y530:~/rtlwifi_new$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822] (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
    Kernel modules: rtwpci
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no


nitish@Lenovo-Legion-Y530:~/rtlwifi_new$ dmesg | grep rtw
[   11.697579] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: Firmware version 13.1.0, H2C version 6
[   11.839161] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0 wlp7s0f0: renamed from wlan0
[   31.153772] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[   31.153779] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: mac power on failed
[   31.153780] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to power on mac
[   33.597618] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[   33.597625] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: mac power on failed
[   33.597627] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to power on mac
[   35.760004] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[   35.760012] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: mac power on failed
[   35.760013] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to power on mac
[   48.181900] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[   48.181908] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: mac power on failed
[   48.181909] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to power on mac
[   50.349350] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[   50.349357] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: mac power on failed
[   50.349359] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to power on mac
[   63.186854] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[   63.186861] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: mac power on failed
[   63.186862] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to power on mac
[   65.355119] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[   65.355126] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: mac power on failed
[   65.355127] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to power on mac
[   78.161145] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[   78.161153] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: mac power on failed
[   78.161154] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to power on mac
[   80.334851] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[   80.334858] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: mac power on failed
[   80.334859] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to power on mac
[   93.061333] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[   93.061340] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: mac power on failed
[   93.061341] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to power on mac
[   95.231662] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[   95.231669] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: mac power on failed
[   95.231669] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to power on mac
[  108.036114] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[  108.036122] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: mac power on failed
[  108.036123] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to power on mac
[  110.205476] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[  110.205483] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: mac power on failed
[  110.205484] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: failed to power on mac
```

I have even tried following steps but that didn't made any difference

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git

cd rtlwifi_new
git checkout extended
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r rtl8822be
sudo modprobe rtl8822be
```

**NOTE**: Things worked perfectly over Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Did you install drivers on 18.04? It looks that the new `rtw_pci` is not perfect.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add output of `dmesg | grep rtw`

Comment: I don't remember it now. But, I actually did a fresh installation of 20.04. Deleted 18.04 completely

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: So `rtw` doesn't work. You never mentioned if `rtlwifi_new` even was built. It seems that you run commands, pay no attention to their output, and see "works" or doesn't. This is not a good way.

Comment: My Lenovo ThinkPad E495 uses the same WIFI chip, but works with Lubuntu 20.04. One issue I have, though, that it takes several attempts every time to connect to my UPC router; but once it works, it works flawless. (Had the same problem with 18.04)

Comment: @Pilot6, I didn't mention until I tried it. Updated the question as soon as I got to know about rtlwifi_new and after trying it. rtw fails for sure that's why I added the complete output of it

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller How did you resolve your wifi issue? I faced it with 18.04 as well. I remember that adding blacklist ideapad_laptop in blacklist.conf resolved it for 18.04

Comment: Turns out that there is a bug in kernel 5.3 due to which REaltek RT2288be doesn't work with Ubuntu 20.04. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1853050 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1872984

Comment: @NitishBhardwaj Actually I did not solve it yet. When I start my notebook, I just keep trying to reconnect until it works. Annoying, but yeah.

Comment: I had no choice but to revert back to 18.04, waiting for community to fix kernel issue

Comment: It was a problem for me too, I didn't actually revert back to 18.04 but switch to the old kernel in grub. The problem is only in the kernel driver, so using an old kernel (4.15) solved the problem.

Comment: ohh great, could you please share how did you downgrade to older version of kernel?

Comment: Is there any other issue or problem that you faced after you downgraded the kernel version?

Answer (score 1):

I have Lenovo Ideapad 530S, after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04 WI-FI stopped working.

This post helped me:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1271087/972111

```
sudo apt install build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/mid-kid/r8822be.git
cd r8822be
./make

# remove the misbehaving rtw88 module
sudo rmmod rtwpci rtw88

# install the r8822be module
sudo ./make install
sudo modprobe r8822be
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Is there anyway to install it in such a way that after kernel updates, you won't have to do this steps everytime since this way you're only building the driver for a particular kernel?

Comment: After trying out different things for days, I decided to switch to a different OS. I am using Solus. Its an individual distro and has good community support. Plus it's not based on any other OS like elementaryOS is based on Ubuntu. First OS which is focused to make developers life easier. I am not facing any wifi issues with it. I would really recommend checking that out. I have been using it for a year and haven't faced a single issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Lenovo Ideapad, Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS with 5.11.0.27 kernel using a PCI Realtek 8822be Wi-Fi/Bluetooth adapter.

I tried [Bulat's driver fix](https://askubuntu.com/a/1284601/348964) above, but it did not work long term.
Finally I found a post that suggested turning **off** Wi-Fi power control using this command:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

and that did the trick.

Comment: That's nice!!! So did you reverted the steps you tried earlier with Bulat's Driver Fix?

Comment: @Max were there any other steps to be taken with your solution? I have tried the same command to no success.