# No connections after upgrade to 20.04 wifi rtw8822be

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, realtek-wireless

After upgrading to 20.04 (from 18.x) my wifi doesn't seem to find any networks

I have tried installing the rtw88 as well as other drivers and suggestions but none seem to work in my case.

Something similar happened when I installed 18.x on my computer but simply adding the rtlwifi_new drivers did the trick. I tried doing what I did with the install of 18.04 but the rtlwifi_new is not available anymore and my old version returns a bug upon make. Issues with 5.4 kernel.

I tried following these threads as well, but unsuccessfully : [rtl8822be wifi driver ubuntu 20.04 hp 15-da1009ne](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229669/rtl8822be-wifi-driver-ubuntu-20-04-hp-15-da1009ne)
https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-rtl8822be-wifi-driver-ubuntu-20-04-hp-15-da1009ne/

here is some log info:
`$ lshw -C network`

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-generic DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:73:00.0
       logical name: wlp115s0
       version: ff
       serial: 80:2b:f9:da:50:e7
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8822be driverversion=5.4.0-48-generic firmware=N/A latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:144 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:6b600000-6b60ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@4:2.4
       logical name: enx00e04c782e5b
       serial: 00:e0:4c:78:2e:5b
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.10.11 duplex=full ip=192.168.0.19 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

`$ lsmod |grep rtw`

```
rtw_8822be             16384  0
rtw_8822b             225280  1 rtw_8822be
rtw_pci                24576  1 rtw_8822be
rtw_core              167936  2 rtw_8822b,rtw_pci
mac80211              843776  2 rtw_core,rtw_pci
cfg80211              704512  2 rtw_core,mac80211
```

`$ dmesg | grep rtw`

```
[    5.116758] rtw_core: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    5.124827] rtw_core: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    5.139159] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    5.143056] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: Firmware version 27.2.0, H2C version 13
[    5.528197] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0 wlp115s0: renamed from wlan0
[    7.832844] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: start vif 80:2b:f9:da:50:e7 on port 0
[    7.994212] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 1068 at /home/vincent/rtw88/pci.c:1173 rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[    7.994212] Modules linked in: vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_core coretemp snd_hwdep kvm_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc snd_pcm videobuf2_memops kvm videobuf2_v4l2 crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_common rtw_8822be(OE) rtw_8822b(OE) ghash_clmulni_intel rtw_pci(OE) cdc_ether videodev usbnet rtw_core(OE) snd_seq_midi btusb r8152 snd_seq_midi_event btrtl nls_iso8859_1 btbcm joydev aesni_intel btintel i915 mii mc snd_rawmidi mac80211 crypto_simd input_leds bluetooth snd_seq cryptd glue_helper ecdh_generic ecc rapl
[    7.994281] RIP: 0010:rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[    7.994295]  rtw_pci_link_ps+0x54/0x90 [rtw_pci]
[    7.994302]  rtw_leave_ips+0x1f/0x80 [rtw_core]
[    7.994306]  rtw_ops_config+0xa3/0xe0 [rtw_core]
[    7.994464] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
[    9.994582] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[    9.994585] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: mac power on failed
[    9.994586] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to power on mac
[    9.994587] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: leave idle state failed
[    9.994724] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to leave ips state
[    9.994725] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to leave idle state
[   15.753871] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[   15.754143] WARNING: CPU: 5 PID: 8 at /home/vincent/rtw88/pci.c:1173 rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   15.754144] Modules linked in: rfcomm vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_core coretemp snd_hwdep kvm_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc snd_pcm videobuf2_memops kvm videobuf2_v4l2 crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_common rtw_8822be(OE) rtw_8822b(OE) ghash_clmulni_intel rtw_pci(OE) cdc_ether videodev usbnet rtw_core(OE) snd_seq_midi btusb r8152 snd_seq_midi_event btrtl nls_iso8859_1 btbcm joydev aesni_intel btintel i915 mii mc snd_rawmidi mac80211 crypto_simd input_leds bluetooth snd_seq cryptd glue_helper ecdh_generic ecc
[   15.754223] RIP: 0010:rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   15.754236]  rtw_pci_link_ps+0x54/0x90 [rtw_pci]
[   15.754241]  ? rtw_core_stop+0xab/0xc0 [rtw_core]
[   15.754246]  rtw_enter_ips+0x3e/0x50 [rtw_core]
[   15.754249]  rtw_ops_config+0xd3/0xe0 [rtw_core]
[   15.754320] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
[   27.379462] WARNING: CPU: 5 PID: 1068 at /home/vincent/rtw88/pci.c:1173 rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   27.379463] Modules linked in: thunderbolt rfcomm vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_core coretemp snd_hwdep kvm_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc snd_pcm videobuf2_memops kvm videobuf2_v4l2 crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_common rtw_8822be(OE) rtw_8822b(OE) ghash_clmulni_intel rtw_pci(OE) cdc_ether videodev usbnet rtw_core(OE) snd_seq_midi btusb r8152 snd_seq_midi_event btrtl nls_iso8859_1 btbcm joydev aesni_intel btintel i915 mii mc snd_rawmidi mac80211 crypto_simd input_leds bluetooth snd_seq cryptd glue_helper
[   27.379537] RIP: 0010:rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   27.379554]  rtw_pci_link_ps+0x54/0x90 [rtw_pci]
[   27.379562]  rtw_leave_ips+0x1f/0x80 [rtw_core]
[   27.379568]  rtw_ops_config+0xa3/0xe0 [rtw_core]
[   27.379753] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
[   29.379828] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[   29.379833] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: mac power on failed
[   29.379835] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to power on mac
[   29.379836] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: leave idle state failed
[   29.380021] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to leave ips state
[   29.380023] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to leave idle state
[   35.125349] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[   35.125613] WARNING: CPU: 7 PID: 206 at /home/vincent/rtw88/pci.c:1173 rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   35.125613] Modules linked in: thunderbolt rfcomm vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_core coretemp snd_hwdep kvm_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc snd_pcm videobuf2_memops kvm videobuf2_v4l2 crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_common rtw_8822be(OE) rtw_8822b(OE) ghash_clmulni_intel rtw_pci(OE) cdc_ether videodev usbnet rtw_core(OE) snd_seq_midi btusb r8152 snd_seq_midi_event btrtl nls_iso8859_1 btbcm joydev aesni_intel btintel i915 mii mc snd_rawmidi mac80211 crypto_simd input_leds bluetooth snd_seq cryptd glue_helper
[   35.125674] RIP: 0010:rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   35.125684]  rtw_pci_link_ps+0x54/0x90 [rtw_pci]
[   35.125688]  ? rtw_core_stop+0xab/0xc0 [rtw_core]
[   35.125691]  rtw_enter_ips+0x3e/0x50 [rtw_core]
[   35.125694]  rtw_ops_config+0xd3/0xe0 [rtw_core]
[   35.125740] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
[   61.018023] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1068 at /home/vincent/rtw88/pci.c:1173 rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   61.018024] Modules linked in: thunderbolt rfcomm vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_core coretemp snd_hwdep kvm_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc snd_pcm videobuf2_memops kvm videobuf2_v4l2 crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_common rtw_8822be(OE) rtw_8822b(OE) ghash_clmulni_intel rtw_pci(OE) cdc_ether videodev usbnet rtw_core(OE) snd_seq_midi btusb r8152 snd_seq_midi_event btrtl nls_iso8859_1 btbcm joydev aesni_intel btintel i915 mii mc snd_rawmidi mac80211 crypto_simd input_leds bluetooth snd_seq cryptd glue_helper
[   61.018072] RIP: 0010:rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   61.018084]  rtw_pci_link_ps+0x54/0x90 [rtw_pci]
[   61.018091]  rtw_leave_ips+0x1f/0x80 [rtw_core]
[   61.018094]  rtw_ops_config+0xa3/0xe0 [rtw_core]
[   61.018237] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
[   63.018342] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[   63.018346] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: mac power on failed
[   63.018348] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to power on mac
[   63.018349] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: leave idle state failed
[   63.018468] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to leave ips state
[   63.018469] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to leave idle state
[   68.789424] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[   68.789761] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 1000 at /home/vincent/rtw88/pci.c:1173 rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   68.789762] Modules linked in: thunderbolt rfcomm vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_core coretemp snd_hwdep kvm_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc snd_pcm videobuf2_memops kvm videobuf2_v4l2 crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_common rtw_8822be(OE) rtw_8822b(OE) ghash_clmulni_intel rtw_pci(OE) cdc_ether videodev usbnet rtw_core(OE) snd_seq_midi btusb r8152 snd_seq_midi_event btrtl nls_iso8859_1 btbcm joydev aesni_intel btintel i915 mii mc snd_rawmidi mac80211 crypto_simd input_leds bluetooth snd_seq cryptd glue_helper
[   68.789870] RIP: 0010:rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   68.789880]  rtw_pci_link_ps+0x54/0x90 [rtw_pci]
[   68.789891]  ? rtw_core_stop+0xab/0xc0 [rtw_core]
[   68.789894]  rtw_enter_ips+0x3e/0x50 [rtw_core]
[   68.789896]  rtw_ops_config+0xd3/0xe0 [rtw_core]
[   68.789951] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
[  104.028921] WARNING: CPU: 6 PID: 1068 at /home/vincent/rtw88/pci.c:1173 rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[  104.028923] Modules linked in: thunderbolt rfcomm vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_core coretemp snd_hwdep kvm_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc snd_pcm videobuf2_memops kvm videobuf2_v4l2 crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_common rtw_8822be(OE) rtw_8822b(OE) ghash_clmulni_intel rtw_pci(OE) cdc_ether videodev usbnet rtw_core(OE) snd_seq_midi btusb r8152 snd_seq_midi_event btrtl nls_iso8859_1 btbcm joydev aesni_intel btintel i915 mii mc snd_rawmidi mac80211 crypto_simd input_leds bluetooth snd_seq cryptd glue_helper
[  104.029107] RIP: 0010:rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[  104.029146]  rtw_pci_link_ps+0x54/0x90 [rtw_pci]
[  104.029164]  rtw_leave_ips+0x1f/0x80 [rtw_core]
[  104.029176]  rtw_ops_config+0xa3/0xe0 [rtw_core]
[  104.029605] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
[  106.029632] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[  106.029636] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: mac power on failed
[  106.029637] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to power on mac
[  106.029638] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: leave idle state failed
[  106.029756] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to leave ips state
[  106.029757] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to leave idle state
[  111.770942] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[  111.771213] WARNING: CPU: 6 PID: 8 at /home/vincent/rtw88/pci.c:1173 rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[  111.771214] Modules linked in: thunderbolt rfcomm vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_core coretemp snd_hwdep kvm_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc snd_pcm videobuf2_memops kvm videobuf2_v4l2 crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_common rtw_8822be(OE) rtw_8822b(OE) ghash_clmulni_intel rtw_pci(OE) cdc_ether videodev usbnet rtw_core(OE) snd_seq_midi btusb r8152 snd_seq_midi_event btrtl nls_iso8859_1 btbcm joydev aesni_intel btintel i915 mii mc snd_rawmidi mac80211 crypto_simd input_leds bluetooth snd_seq cryptd glue_helper
[  111.771298] RIP: 0010:rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[  111.771312]  rtw_pci_link_ps+0x54/0x90 [rtw_pci]
[  111.771318]  ? rtw_core_stop+0xab/0xc0 [rtw_core]
[  111.771322]  rtw_enter_ips+0x3e/0x50 [rtw_core]
[  111.771326]  rtw_ops_config+0xd3/0xe0 [rtw_core]
[  111.771399] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
[  157.018863] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1068 at /home/vincent/rtw88/pci.c:1173 rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[  157.018865] Modules linked in: thunderbolt rfcomm vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_core coretemp snd_hwdep kvm_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc snd_pcm videobuf2_memops kvm videobuf2_v4l2 crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_common rtw_8822be(OE) rtw_8822b(OE) ghash_clmulni_intel rtw_pci(OE) cdc_ether videodev usbnet rtw_core(OE) snd_seq_midi btusb r8152 snd_seq_midi_event btrtl nls_iso8859_1 btbcm joydev aesni_intel btintel i915 mii mc snd_rawmidi mac80211 crypto_simd input_leds bluetooth snd_seq cryptd glue_helper
[  157.019021] RIP: 0010:rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[  157.019063]  rtw_pci_link_ps+0x54/0x90 [rtw_pci]
[  157.019083]  rtw_leave_ips+0x1f/0x80 [rtw_core]
[  157.019095]  rtw_ops_config+0xa3/0xe0 [rtw_core]
[  157.019601] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
[  159.019803] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[  159.019807] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: mac power on failed
[  159.019808] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to power on mac
[  159.019809] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: leave idle state failed
[  159.019962] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to leave ips state
[  159.019963] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to leave idle state
[  164.766045] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[  164.766328] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 1000 at /home/vincent/rtw88/pci.c:1173 rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[  164.766328] Modules linked in: thunderbolt rfcomm vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_core coretemp snd_hwdep kvm_intel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc snd_pcm videobuf2_memops kvm videobuf2_v4l2 crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_common rtw_8822be(OE) rtw_8822b(OE) ghash_clmulni_intel rtw_pci(OE) cdc_ether videodev usbnet rtw_core(OE) snd_seq_midi btusb r8152 snd_seq_midi_event btrtl nls_iso8859_1 btbcm joydev aesni_intel btintel i915 mii mc snd_rawmidi mac80211 crypto_simd input_leds bluetooth snd_seq cryptd glue_helper
[  164.766385] RIP: 0010:rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[  164.766394]  rtw_pci_link_ps+0x54/0x90 [rtw_pci]
[  164.766398]  ? rtw_core_stop+0xab/0xc0 [rtw_core]
[  164.766401]  rtw_enter_ips+0x3e/0x50 [rtw_core]
[  164.766403]  rtw_ops_config+0xd3/0xe0 [rtw_core]
[  164.766448] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
[  183.883135] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: stop vif 80:2b:f9:da:50:e7 on port 0
[  185.883305] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[  194.050934] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[  194.050939] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: mac power on failed
[  194.050940] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to power on mac
[  196.051691] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[  196.051695] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: mac power on failed
[  196.051697] rtw_8822be 0000:73:00.0: failed to power on mac
```

I hope someone can help me fix this :D

Thanks a lot!!!

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the ASPM on rtw_pci module, blocking the physical WiFi module. You may find a trace in dmesg

disable the ASPM on this module :

```
echo "options rtw_pci disable_aspm=Y"  | sudo tee  /etc/modprobe.d/rtw_pci.conf
```

Then the difficulty will be to reset physically the module. This can be done with one of the following solutions :

- disconnect physically the Wifi module
- unplug (and if it is a laptop) remove the battery
- in case of multi-boot, boot on Windows until you can start WiFi on Windows

EDIT : Sometimes, just restarting the laptop is enough...